# What is this monster from limbo with a scythe?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, content-identification

I remember a 3.5e monster I read about a few years back, but I can't remember its name or what book I got it from. It was in a printed 3.5e book.

Here's what I remember:

- Native to the plane of limbo
- Outsider with a very undead like look
- Chaotic Evil
- Attacked with a scythe

Does anyone know what monster it is?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you truly refer to an Outsider, that can only be Ygorl, the Slaad Lord of Entropy, and the closest thing Limbo has to a ruler. It is huge, chaotic evil, and has the appearance of a blackened humanoid skeleton. Its weapon of choice is a scythe. It was originally detailed in the 1981 *Fiend Folio*, published by TSR long before 3.5e was even imagined.

There is an unofficial 3.5e update to Ygorl available [here](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?92837-Limbo-4-0-(3-5-PEACH)-COMPLETE&p=5053296&viewfull=1#post5053296), by the noted Planescape expert afroakuma.

Beyond Ygorl, however, the 2004 3.5e book *Libris Mortis* includes the entropic reapers, which are truly undead rather than Outsiders, but they are native to Limbo and share a similar appearance with Ygorl. *Libris Mortis* does not mention Ygorl, but the entropic reapers’ appearance and association with entropy is enough to link them. They are notable for their *plane shift* ability, and their proclivity for spending a lot of time on the Material Plane rather than Limbo.